# How to generate 3 natural number that sum to 60 using awk

Tags: linux, awk, gawk

I am trying to write awk script that generate 3 natural numbers that sum to 60. I am trying with rand function but I`ve got problem with sum to 60

Comment: generate 2 random numbers and calculate 3rd one as (60 - number1 - number2)

Comment: @Lashane rand() generates floating point, so it may be a problem. Tomasz, you can generate 3 random floats, divide all by their sum and multiply them by 60, you'll get 3 numbers that sum to 60. Then round them (check for upwards/downwards to compensate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
awk -v n=60 'BEGIN{srand();a=int(rand()*n);b=int(rand()*(n-a));c=n-a-b;
             print a,b,c}'
```

Idea is:

- generate random number `a` :`0=<a<60`
- generate random number `b` :`0=<b<60-a`
- `c=60-a-b`

here, I set a variable `n=60`, to make it easy if you have other sum.

If we run this one-liner 10 times, we get output:

```
kent$  awk 'BEGIN{srand();for(i=1;i<=10;i++){a=int(rand()*60);b=int(rand()*(60-a));c=60-a-b;print a,b,c}}'
46 7 7
56 1 3
26 15 19
14 12 34
44 6 10
1 36 23
32 1 27
41 0 19
55 1 4
54 1 5
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i need

Comment: But this isn't so good in terms of probabilistic distribution.